# emacs: clear(erase) the python result console in the emacs

Tags: python, emacs, console

Hi I am using the emacs and elpy to run the python code as shown in the figure. Since the output result is so many, I want to erase or clear the console result. I want to make the console result be empty or clear. Is there emacs keys to clear the python console in the emacs or how to set it. Thanks in advance!
[image: running python in emacs]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use `M-x erase-buffer` to clear the *Python* buffer (or any other buffer)

Answer (score 20):

With your point in the `*Python*` buffer, run:

`C-c M-o`

or
`M-x comint-clear-buffer`

Comment: This works because the shell provisioned by `C-c C-p` or `M-x run-python` is built on top of `comint-mode`. This is a mode responsible for  command-interpreter-in-buffer like functionality.